# After upgrading to 11.10 and attempting to install Wine, I get "the method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/ppa could not be found"

Tags: 11.10, ppa

Additionally, no file with the name "ppa" exists in /usr/lib/apt/methods. Any idea what might have happened to that file, and how I might recreate it?  BTW, this was after upgrading from 11.04 via the gui upgrade path.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, the problem was related to having added the line "ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa oneiric main" in the software sources application on the desktop and then subsequently trying to use apt-get from a terminal. Removing the line from the gui software sources application fixed the problem. Not sure where that line is stored, but it certainly wasn't in /etc/apt/sources.list.

The line "ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa" came from the instructions on the page:
 https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ppa